# Failed to plot simple graph in Octave

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, octave

I want to draw a line on a graph to find the intersection point with another line. However, there's no response after I executed the script below. May I know what is the problem and how can I solve it?

```
x=1:2^20;
y2=2^24;
plot(x,y2);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your x contains all numbers from 1 to 2^20=1048576, if you insert such large data into the plot function it is slow or may run out of memory.

Comment: Are you sure that y2 is supposed to be a scalar?

Comment: as Daniel a sobek suggested: You x and y data should be the same size! in your case x is a 1048577x1 vector while y2 is 1x1 (a number)

Comment: @AnderBiguri   Yes, I wanted to solve an inequality ((k+1)(ln k)<2^24), and my idea was to use a graph and an intersection point to get a result.  Do you have any suggestions of solving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to plot a line on 2^24. However, there are too many points for you computer probably, and you run out of memory

I am guessing that you'll need to plot your other inequality as well.

Something like

```
x=1:100:2^20;                    
% As Zoran and others suggested, You may not want all the points!
% It is too much memory
y2=2^24*ones(size(x)); % This ones is optional, but its good to know what you are doing (personal opinion)
plot(x,y2);
hold on
y1=(x+1).*log(x);
plot(x,y1);
```

[image]

However, you are still not there!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, which does not rely on plotting:

```
>> f = @(x) (x+1)*log(x)-2^24;
>> soln = fzero(f,1e6)
soln =   1.1987e+006
>> f(soln)
ans =   3.7253e-009
```

So your intersection point is at `1.1987e6`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently,you have too many points for x,  2^20
Have to wait program to calculate, or plot,for example, every 100th point

This solution works for Matlab

```
x=1:100:2^20;
y2=2^2;
plot(x,y2,'o');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more and maybe a bit smarter way: if you want to solve ((k+1)(ln k)<2^24) as you've commented above, use `fsolve` function to get just solution of an equation(!). Then use that solution to specify the area of your interest, so you won't have to plot the domain of 2^20.
(All functions are continuous so you don't have to worry about any wild singularities. Just examine the neigborhood of ks for which (k+1)(ln k)-2^24=0.)